# How to add a progressbar in Laravel chunk function

Tags: laravel-5

I want to do something with customer table and there are lot of records so I will use chunk function to do it per 100 records. And I also want to add a progress bar to display the progress.

but the code I write does not work .
the error occurs at "$bar" variable.

```
$count = DB::table('customers')->count();
$bar = $this->output->createProgressBar($count);

DB::table('customers')->chunk(100, function ($customers,$bar) {
  foreach($customers as $customer) {
   //do something with customer
   $bar->advance();
  }
  $bar->finish();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is the correct way:

```
->chunk(100, function ($users) use ($bar){}
```

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is 50% correct.

`DB::table('customers')->chunk` is running per 100 rows, so you have to add `$bar->finish();` out of the callback

```
$count = DB::table('customers')->count();
$bar = $this->output->createProgressBar($count);

DB::table('customers')->chunk(100, function ($customers,$bar) use($bar) {
  foreach($customers as $customer) {
   //do something with customer
   $bar->advance();
  }
});
$bar->finish();
```